# SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'photo-storage.images' doesn't exist (SQL: insert into `images` ())

Tags: mysql, database

When I save a image in database (phpmyadmin), had error:

> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'photo-storage.images' doesn't exist (SQL: insert into `images` value(...))`

Before that, I do

```
DROP TABLE images

CREATE TABLE images(
    image_id INT(4) PRIMARY KEY,
    image VARCHAR(200);
```

But have error

> #1813 - Tablespace for table '`photo-storage`.`images`' exists.
>   Please DISCARD the tablespace before IMPORT.

I checked phpmyadmin. However, I don't see images table[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/13sHo.png)

I deleted `C:\xampp\mysql\data\photo_storage\images.ibd` but it not working

[image]

Comment: Are you creating the tables directly with a query in phpMyAdmin, or are you doing it through migrations?

Comment: I'm creating the tables directly with a query in phpMyAdmin